# very slow tests through selenium grid

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

machine1:
`java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.43.1.jar -role hub`

machine2:
`java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.43.1.jar -role node -browser browserName=chrome,maxInstances=1`

All tests go to web app on the third machine. From fourth machine I run same amount of tests:

- locally: 0m27s
- remotely through grid: 2m50s

All of them running on the same local network. Why it's so slow then?
What should I check to find the bottleneck?

UPDATE1: ping between all machines ~0.03ms-0.89ms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was in abnormal load at the machine1 with grid server proccess running.

```
  # uptime
  14:35:31 up 9 days, 21:55,  2 users,  load average: 2.86, 2.18, 2.16
```

I moved selenium grid server process to other fresh machine and everything speeds up.

Answer (score 1):

I'd check the ping times between the servers. (I'm assuming in every case the test are running through the grid.)

If not, the grid is going to be your bottleneck.

You can speed things up if you keep in mind that every time you try to retrieve something from the web page, it has to go through the grid.  Many times you can cache information.

I wrote about that here: http://blog.dmbcllc.com/selenium-performance-improvements/

Comment: Added ping info. Also as far as I know, in ruby I don't have access to ```CacheLookup``` property. And the weirdiest thing is that a few days ago everything works pretty fast, I don't change the version of selenium-server.jar file and do nothing with local network.

Comment: You may not be able to cache using an attribute like you can in Java and .NET, but you can do it with your own  code.